# Getting error on PDO Execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to figure out the problem with my code.

At one file I have this:

```
$dbConnect->openDbConnection();
$dbExec = $dbConnect->conn->prepare("SELECT nome, direc FROM condoInfo WHERE idCondo = " + $condoInfo);
$dbExec->execute();
```

As a result I get : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

what is the problem in here? Since I«m not understanding it very well

Comment: the concatenating operator is . in php not +

Comment: haha...  Your error TELLS you its a syntax error, and to look it up.  Mihai is correct.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: The error is a MySQL syntax error, not a PHP one.

Comment: No, your PHP error is causing a MySQL error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat If you `echo "SELECT nome, direc FROM condoInfo WHERE idCondo = " + 3;` then the output is simply "3". OP is essentially telling MySQL to execute a SQL query using nothing more than the value of `$condoInfo`. OP's PHP code is the root cause of the MySQL error.

Comment: OP probably comes from a C/JS background. Edit: Seeing their [c++ tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3310091+[c%2b%2b]), I was right. In PHP, concatenation is a dot and not a plus sign, *remember that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the concatenation is incorrect. You use `.` in php not `+` to concatenate. Next, with prepared statements, you should be binding user input through parameterized queries. Let's have a look:

```
$dbExec = $dbConnect->conn->prepare("SELECT nome, direc FROM condoInfo WHERE idCondo = :id");
$dbExec->bindParam(':id', $condoInfo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbExec->execute();
```

This will make sure your user data is sanitized correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working now :D, main problem of the . and +, is that I'm use to work with another languanges, and hasn't put my hands on php for quite some time hehe

Answer (score 0):

It will be good practice to define query in separate variable and then use it like that .

```
 $query = "SELECT nome, direc FROM condoInfo WHERE idCondo = " . $condoInfo;
 $dbConnect->openDbConnection();
 $dbExec = $dbConnect->conn->prepare($query);
 $dbExec->execute();
```

Print your query separately and check that is there any error in the query or not by running the query on your db prompt .

```
 echo $query ;
```